# On a graphic I want to put the populations by year for 44 cities. But the "plot" statement for the first city isn't completed by "lines" of the others

Tags: r

I want to draw the populations evolving year by year for the cities of a local authority in France (called : *intercommunalité* here) on the same graphic.

I am a beginner with `R`, and I run into a problem :
whilst console log seems to show that populations given for each city looks always in the same format, my graphic shows only a single line for the populations of the first city, and not the 43 other ones.

What have I done wrong ?
Thanks !

```
# Charger les intercommunalités et les limiter à celles à fiscalité propre.
intercos = read.csv(file="f:/data/dev-compte-france/territoire/2018/groupements3.csv", header = T, sep='\t');
intercos = subset(intercos, intercos$Nature.juridique == "CA" | intercos$Nature.juridique == "CC" | intercos$Nature.juridique == "CU" | intercos$Nature.juridique == "METRO" | intercos$Nature.juridique == "MET69" | intercos$Nature.juridique == "EPT")
comptes = read.csv(file="f:/data/dev-compte-france/balances-comptes/comptes-communes-2000-2017.csv", header = T, sep=',');

# Nous nous limitons aux communes d'une intercommunalité.
communes_entr_allier = c("03298", "03014", "03019", "03034", "03067", "03071", "03079", "03091", "03100", "03102", "03132", "03137", "03035", "03103", "03142", "03208", "03144", "03147", "03154", "03171", "03177", "03178", "03179", "03181", "03187", "03196", "03207", "03215", "03226", "03232", "03234", "03235", "03239", "03240", "03253", "03263", "03265", "03266", "03274", "03284", "03289", "03291", "03299", "03300")
entr_allier = subset(comptes, comptes$depcom %in% communes_entr_allier)

# Axes des X : Années
# Axes des Y : Population
annee_debut = min(unique(entr_allier$annee));
annee_fin = max(unique(entr_allier$annee));
population_min = min(entr_allier$population);
population_max = max(entr_allier$population);

# Les courbes vont prendre des couleurs de l'arc en ciel pour se distinguer les unes les autres.
couleurs = rainbow(length(communes_entr_allier));

# Tracer la première courbe avec plot pour initialiser le graphique.
indexCommune = 1;
population = subset(entr_allier$population, entr_allier$depcom == communes_entr_allier[indexCommune]);  

print(sprintf("années comprises entre %d et %d, populations des %d communes entre %d et %d.", annee_debut, annee_fin, length(communes_entr_allier), population_min, population_max));
print(sprintf("Courbe n° %d : commune %s : %d entrées de population présentes : ", indexCommune, communes_entr_allier[indexCommune], length(population)));
print(population);

plot(x = unique(entr_allier$annee), xlim = c(annee_debut, annee_fin), xlab = "Année",
     y = population, ylim = c(population_min, population_max), ylab = "Population de la commune",
     type="l");

# Tracer les courbes correspondant à la population annuelle des autres communes.
for(indexCommune in 2:length(communes_entr_allier)){
  # Extraire les données de population dans le temps limitées à la commune en cours de traçage.
  population = subset(entr_allier$population, entr_allier$depcom == communes_entr_allier[indexCommune]);  

  print(sprintf("Courbe n° %d : commune %s : %d entrées de population présentes : ", indexCommune, communes_entr_allier[indexCommune], length(population)));
  print(population);

  lines(population,                   # Population de la commune.
        col = couleurs[indexCommune], # à tracer dans l'une des couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel.
        type="l");                    # En type "Ligne"
}
```

When I run it, it ends normally, but shows only the `plot` output. Not the others `lines` statements.

```
[1] "années comprises entre 2000 et 2017, populations des 44 communes entre 141 et 4316."
[1] "Courbe n° 1 : commune 03298 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
[1] 4316 4316 4316 4316 4316 4316 4316 4316 4316 3931 3887 3832 3759 3671 3645 3614 3621 3625
[1] "Courbe n° 2 : commune 03014 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 181 181 181 181 181 181 181 181 181 173 172 167 162 160 156 150 146 143
[1] "Courbe n° 3 : commune 03019 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 1582 1582 1582 1582 1582 1582 1582 1582 1582 1629 1629 1636 1636 1643 1668 1685 1696 1701
[1] "Courbe n° 4 : commune 03034 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 523 523 523 523 523 523 523 523 523 558 563 568 570 568 555 542 530 526
[1] "Courbe n° 5 : commune 03067 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 141 141 141 141 141 141 141 141 141 147 147 149 151 154 156 159 153 149
[1] "Courbe n° 6 : commune 03071 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 258 258 258 258 258 258 258 258 258 277 281 285 288 278 270 262 264 265
[1] "Courbe n° 7 : commune 03079 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 319 319 319 319 319 319 319 319 319 324 323 322 328 332 339 338 332 326
[1] "Courbe n° 8 : commune 03091 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 450 450 450 450 450 450 450 450 450 466 474 481 488 494 500 493 486 479
[1] "Courbe n° 9 : commune 03100 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 1595 1595 1595 1595 1595 1595 1595 1595 1595 1547 1563 1539 1534 1531 1517 1525 1491 1461
[1] "Courbe n° 10 : commune 03102 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 3577 3577 3577 3577 3577 3577 3577 3577 3577 3395 3385 3307 3263 3232 3199 3205 3189 3163
[1] "Courbe n° 11 : commune 03132 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 709 709 709 709 709 709 709 709 709 677 668 662 647 637 617 611 605 604
[1] "Courbe n° 12 : commune 03137 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 225 236 238 240 242 242 252 263 275 278
[1] "Courbe n° 13 : commune 03035 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 223 223 223 223 223 223 223 223 223 219 217 220 216 213 211 210 209 211
[1] "Courbe n° 14 : commune 03103 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 1191 1191 1191 1191 1191 1191 1191 1191 1191 1123 1085 1085 1095 1101 1106 1108 1108 1107
[1] "Courbe n° 15 : commune 03142 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 298 298 298 298 298 298 298 298 298 260 254 248 248 244 252 260 268 267
[1] "Courbe n° 16 : commune 03208 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 388 388 388 388 388 388 388 388 388 372 379 385 395 401 407 414 416 415
[1] "Courbe n° 17 : commune 03144 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 287 287 287 287 287 287 287 287 287 263 259 262 265 255 237 222 218 214
[1] "Courbe n° 18 : commune 03147 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 193 164 160 156 153 151 159 165 170 168
[1] "Courbe n° 19 : commune 03154 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 295 295 295 295 295 295 295 295 295 283 289 291 293 294 291 289 293 298
[1] "Courbe n° 20 : commune 03171 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 296 296 296 296 296 296 296 296 296 301 303 290 280 269 267 263 261 264
[1] "Courbe n° 21 : commune 03177 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 347 347 347 347 347 347 347 347 347 297 302 301 298 294 292 290 284 277
[1] "Courbe n° 22 : commune 03178 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 323 323 323 323 323 323 323 323 323 312 312 318 321 325 328 329 329 327
[1] "Courbe n° 23 : commune 03179 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 368 368 368 368 368 368 368 368 368 320 318 317 315 316 316 320 321 321
[1] "Courbe n° 24 : commune 03181 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 439 439 439 439 439 439 439 439 439 424 428 430 404 378 357 349 342 333
[1] "Courbe n° 25 : commune 03187 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 617 617 617 617 617 617 617 617 617 652 656 661 661 649 645 641 645 657
[1] "Courbe n° 26 : commune 03196 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 233 233 233 233 233 233 233 233 233 246 246 245 236 230 225 224 225 222
[1] "Courbe n° 27 : commune 03207 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 548 548 548 548 548 548 548 548 548 521 518 523 523 520 517 515 516 514
[1] "Courbe n° 28 : commune 03215 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 579 579 579 579 579 579 579 579 579 550 548 564 580 595 598 608 596 587
[1] "Courbe n° 29 : commune 03226 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 289 289 289 289 289 289 289 289 289 282 279 277 278 277 272 273 274 278
[1] "Courbe n° 30 : commune 03232 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 254 254 254 254 254 254 336 336 370 321 330 339 349 352 347 343 339 340
[1] "Courbe n° 31 : commune 03234 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 475 475 475 475 475 475 475 475 475 453 450 444 432 428 420 413 413 409
[1] "Courbe n° 32 : commune 03235 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1042 1019 1015 1011 1007 1012 1023 1031 1041 1043
[1] "Courbe n° 33 : commune 03239 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 296 293 297 292 287 282 272 269 272
[1] "Courbe n° 34 : commune 03240 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 662 662 662 662 662 662 662 662 662 631 625 618 612 609 615 621 629 635
[1] "Courbe n° 35 : commune 03253 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 430 425 424 422 420 416 420 431 437 443
[1] "Courbe n° 36 : commune 03263 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 206 206 206 206 206 206 206 206 206 207 205 203 205 206 206 206 202 200
[1] "Courbe n° 37 : commune 03265 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 809 809 809 809 809 809 809 809 809 888 900 904 906 870 833 795 780 768
[1] "Courbe n° 38 : commune 03266 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 355 327 338 307 280 255 259 262 267 269
[1] "Courbe n° 39 : commune 03274 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 287 291 296 302 301 299 301 308 312
[1] "Courbe n° 40 : commune 03284 : 17 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 315 315 315 315 315 315 315 315 326 323 325 327 336 336 335 332 329
[1] "Courbe n° 41 : commune 03289 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 528 528 528 528 528 528 528 528 528 542 548 555 557 569 572 575 578 586
[1] "Courbe n° 42 : commune 03291 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 410 410 410 410 410 410 410 410 410 389 392 392 396 398 402 403 401 403
[1] "Courbe n° 43 : commune 03299 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 265 258 256 254 257 260 263 263 263
[1] "Courbe n° 44 : commune 03300 : 18 entrées de population présentes : "
 [1] 572 572 572 572 572 572 572 572 572 545 555 559 566 565 560 560 560 555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
lines(population,                   # Population de la commune.
        col = couleurs[indexCommune], # à tracer dans l'une des couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel.
        type="l");                    # En type "Ligne"
```

You only give `population` to plot, but the `lines()` function wants two variables, corresponding to the `x` and `y` axes.  You need to give the corresponding years as well.

The way you did that for the first commune looks risky:  you subsetted the populations, but then plotted them against `unique(entr_allier$annee)`.  This assumes that in the original dataset every commune has data for the same set of years and they are in increasing order.  It would be safer to subset the dataframe and plot the subset of years against the subset of population values.